# Power series solution (Why the constant of the recurrence relation can be chosen arbitrarily?)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, power-series, recursion

Please help me understand this:

Solve $(x+1)y''-(2-x)y'+y =0$

First, since $x_0=0$ is an ordinary point, it can be guaranteed that we can find two independent power series solutions centered at $x_0=0$. We substitute $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$ into the equation and we will have:

$$ (x+1)y''-(2-x)y'+y =0 $$
$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [n(n-1)c_nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)c_{n}x^{n-2}]-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_{n}x^n +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}x^n =0 $$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+1)kc_{k+1}x^{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)kc_{k+2}x^{k} - 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)c_{k+1}x^{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kc_{k}x^{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k}x^{k}$$
$$ (2c_{2}-2c_{1}+c_{0}) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} [(k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2} + (k-2)(k+1)c_{k+1} + (k+1)c_{k}]x^k = 0 $$

Thus
$$ 2c_{2}-2c_{1}+c_{0}=0 \tag{1}$$
$$ (k+2)(k+1)c_{k+2}+(k+1)(k-2)c_{k+1}+(k+1)c_{k} = 0 \tag{2}$$
and the last equation gives
$$ c_{k+2} = - \frac{(k-2)c_{k+1}+c_{k}}{k+2}, \quad \textrm{k=1,2,3...} \tag{3}$$

> Now, the part that I don't understand is the part that follows from
>   this. Most textbooks usually proceed from equation$(3)$ by choosing $c_0=1$ and
>   $c_1=0$, without telling any reason, which will give $$c_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}, c_{3}=-\frac{1}{6}, c_{4}=\frac{1}{12},...$$ thus the first solution is $y_{1}=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \frac{1}{12}x^4+...$
>
> Then they choose $c_{0}=0$ and $c_{1}=1$ and they will obtain
>   $$c_{2}=1, c_{3}=0, c_{4}=\frac{1}{4},...$$ thus the second solution is $y_{2}=x+x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^4+...$
>
> And the general solution is $$y=C_{1}(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{6}x^3 + \frac{1}{12}x^4+...)+C_{2}(x+x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^4+...) \tag{4}$$

**My question is** why can we choose $c_0$ and $c_1$ arbitrarily like this? Does this work in a higher or more term of recurrence relation? If I modify $c_0$ and $c_1$, wouldn't it change the subsequent coefficients $c_{k}$? And therefore we will have the solution which is different? (In other words, choosing $c_0=0$ and $c_1=1$ will give one solution, but choosing $c_0=0$ and $c_1=123$ will give another different solution?)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general theory about second order homogeneous differential equations says that (i) there is an open interval $I$ on the $x$-axis containing containing $0$ in its interior such that the given ODE has a two-dimensional vector space ${\cal L}$ of solutions $y(\cdot):\>I\to{\mathbb R}$, and (ii) these solutions are even real analytic, i.e. have convergent power series representations in $I$.

It follows that if you have, by whatever means, found two linearly independent solutions $y_1(\cdot)$ and $y_2(\cdot)$ in the form of power series then the general solution is given by $y(x)=C_1y_1(x)+C_2y_2(x)$ with real constants $C_1$, $C_2$.

By choosing the initial conditions for $y_1(\cdot)$ and $y_2(\cdot)$ in the way you have done you can be sure that these solutions are linearly independent, because each of them has a property that cannot be produced by a linear combination of the others (resp., by a multiple of the other):  You have $y_2'(0)=1$, whereas $y_1'(0)=0$.

Comment: Is there any possibility that this method wouldn't work? I found this DE seems to not work with this method:
$$ y''+y=x $$
If I let $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nx^n$, then by substituting back into the original equation the recurrence relation is given by
$$ [2c_2+c_0]+[6c_3+c_1]x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}[c_{n+1}(n+2)(n+1)+c_n[=x $$
Equating coefficients both side gives
$$ 2c_2+c_0=0 \tag{1}$$
$$ 6c_3+c_1=1  \tag{2}$$
$$ c_{n+2}=-\frac{c_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}, n>1  \tag{3}$$
Now if we set $c_0=1$, $c_1=0$, we will have
$$ c_2=-\frac{1}{2},c_3=\frac{1}{6},c_4=\frac{1}{24}, c_5=-\frac{1}{120},... $$

Comment: Thus the first solution is
$$y_{1}(x)=1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-\frac{1}{5!}x^5-...$$
$$ y_{1}(x)=x+(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4-...)+(-x+\frac{1}{3!}x^3-\frac{1}{5!}x^5)$$
If we set $c_0=0$,$c_1=1$ we will have $ c_2=0, c_3=0, c_4=0, c_5=0,.... $ Thus the second solution is $y_{2}(x)=x$.


The general solution then would be $$y=A[x+\cos(x)-\sin(x)]+B[x]$$But if I solve this using the Principle of Superposition by finding a particular solution and the general solution of homogeneous, it seems it will yield $$ y=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)+x $$ which is not the same?

Comment: @Ignite: The ODE in your question is homogeneous, the ODE $y''+y=x$ is not. The power series "Ansatz" will still give you two free constants; but the general solution is of the form $y(x)=y_p(x)+C_1y_1(x)+C_2y_2(x)$, whereby $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous ODE $y''+y=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I need to study more about this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a second order differential equation, so there are $2$ arbitrary constants in the general solution. As you could see, there was a constraint on $c_2$, but there is none on $c_0$ and $c_1$, and there is no mutual constraint between the latter two constants. It seems most convenient to separate things out into $2$ series, one where all the exponents are divisible by $3$, and the other where the exponents are $\equiv1\pmod3$.

Comment: Sorry if this is too late to ask. What if I have a constraint, for example:
$$ 2c_2 - 2c_1 + c_0 = 0 $$
$$ c_{k+2}=- \frac{(k-2)c_{k+1} + c_{k}}{k+2} \quad \textrm{k=1,2,3...}$$
Now there is a mutual constraint between $c_0$ and $c_1$. It seems too messy to solve for the coefficients in terms of $c_0$ and $c_1$. Setting $c_0=0$, $c_1=1$ first and then $c_0=1$, $c_1=0$ would simplify life pretty much. But can we really set $c_0=0$, $c_1=1$ first and then $c_0=1$, $c_1=0$ ? I don't quite get the picture of this method.

Comment: For Airy's equation as in the original problem statement, life is pretty simple as it reduces to a $2$ term recurrence relation and separates easily into two distinct series. In the more general case life can get really complicated, see the [method of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: I just have edited my question. Actually the solution proposed in the class was to set $c_0=0$,$c_1=1$ and then $c_0=1$,$c_1=0$ (as in the question) which will give two independent solutions. But for some reason, the answer would be "this is the way we do" when I asked this question to my TA in the class. Maybe I have to accept and go on.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that each solution is completed characterized by two numbers $c_0$ and $c_1$. Also, the terms that are influeced by $c_0$ do not overlap with the terms that are influenced by the terms influenced by $c_1$.

In particular observe the relationship:

$$y(c_0,c_1)=c_0y(1,0)+c_1y(0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the previous answers, observe that you can give initial conditions to select a unique solutions. The choice of initial data corresponds with the choice of the constanta $c_0$ and $c_1$:

1. $c_0=1$ and $c_1=0$ corresponds to $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$.
2. $c_0=0$ and $c_1=1$ corresponds to $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Comment: But if I modify $c_0$ and $c_1$, wouldn't it change the subsequent coefficients $c_{k}$? And therefore we will have the solution which is different? (In other words, choosing $c_0=0$ and $c_1=1$ will give one solution, but choosing $c_0=0$ and $c_1=123$ will give another different solution?)

Or are you saying that no matter how we arbitrarily choose $c_0$ and $c_1$, we will finally be able to find the constant $A$ and $B$ such that the general solution $$ y=Ay_{1}+by_{2} $$ satisfy any initial condition?

Comment: Modifying $c_0$ and $c_1$ will change the rest of the coefficients. Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the solutions obtained with the choices indicated in the answer. They are linearly independent, and the general solution will be $y=A\,y_1+B\,y_2$, where $A=y(0)$ and $B=y'(0)$.